# Ajax request a JSON responce from a PHP file - gets the CPU jump to 100% for some of my (heavy data) users

Tags: php, ajax, cpu-usage

Cannot find a solution for this kind of problem:

I have a portal where users can login and generate a CSV files (via ajax request - passing a date range).

This happens via a form that sends an ajax request to a different PHP file that fetches the data from the database, organize it, do some calculations, and generates a readt for download CSV file.

For users who don't have a lot of data via DB - it doesn't take long, and doesn't affect the CPU too much, but for users that do have a lot of data - this gets my CPU a little bit crazy.

My portal is hosted on Amazon AWS EC2 - so whenever the CPU reaches to 100% the server goes down.

How do I prevent this from happening, or limit the CPU for this form (or this ajax request) from reaching 100%CPU?

- DB (MySQL) Tables are properly indexed. Data is fetched properly.
- PHP organizes and calculates the code to prevent long slow DB JOINS and calculation queries.

Comment: the only people who can figure this out, is people with access to your source code.  `PHP file that fetches the data from the database, organize it, do some calculations, and generates a readt for download CSV file.` - the problem is somewhere in the source code of that php file, but since you're not sharing your source code, nobody here can help you.

Comment: You can either optimize your script or purchase faster/more performant EC2 instance. Anyway the first step should be profiling your current code to see where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the lines that might be included in the CSV file total, so that i.e. the total-amount is 10.000 even 100.000 records are in a table.
A more sophisticated approach is to allow even large data but restrict the amount that is processed per minute. So users with data-amount 100.000 have to wait some time by intention (if the server is going down completely they can't access anything anyway).

A resembling restriction was included in [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.de/) to circumvent browser-timeout - but data-limit could be set additionally too.

It'd take some efforts to realize my 2nd proposition but would be comfortable and assure that the server is still able to answer normal web-requests while working on exports.